# Oracle universal installer disappearing before completing

Tags: database, windows, oracle, oracle11g, installation

I've downloaded the Oracle Database 11g (release 2) in a Windows 8.1 system. The Oracle's guide oriented me to login in Administrator Mode at my PC and then click on the Oracle Universal Installer to begin the installation.

And when I click it, it shows something like:

```
    Verifyng monitor. Should be configured to show at least 256 colors superior to 256. Real ones 4294967296. Passed. 
    Preparing to start Oracle Universal Installer of C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2015-05-07-06-40-06PM. Wait...
```

And so it just disappears. It keeps running as I can see at my Task Manager, but I receive no answers from it. Do someone know why this happens?

EDIT: Here is the log:

```
Using paramFile: C:\Program Files\Oracle DB\database\install\oraparam.ini


Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 4294967296    Passed

The commandline for unzip:
C:\Program Files\Oracle DB\database\install\unzip -qqqo ..\stage\Components\oracle.jdk\1.5.0.17.04\1\DataFiles/"*.jar" -d "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2015-05-07_06-44-35PM" INFO: Loading data from: jar:file:/C:/Users/Administrador/AppData/Local/Temp/OraInstall2015-05-07_06-44-35PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
INFO: Loading beanstore from jar:file:/C:/Users/Administrador/AppData/Local/Temp/OraInstall2015-05-07_06-44-35PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
INFO: Restoring class oracle.install.driver.oui.ConfigCmdMappings from jar:file:/C:/Users/Administrador/AppData/Local/Temp/OraInstall2015-05-07_06-44-35PM/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar!/oracle/install/driver/oui/resource/ConfigCommandMappings.xml
INFO: Verifying target environment...
INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined...
SEVERE: CVU do not support target environment..
Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.driver.oui.OUISetupDriver:13
INFO: Completed verification of target environment.
WARNING: Verification of target environment returned with errors.
WARNING: [WARNING] [INS-13001] O ambiente não atende aos requisitos mínimos.
CAUSA: Os requisitos mínimos não foram atendidos para este ambiente
AÇÃO: Verifique os logs para obter mais informações ou verifique as configurações suportadas para este produto..
Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.commons.util.exception.DefaultErrorAdvisor:16
INFO: Advice is WITHDRAW
WARNING: Advised to shutdown the installer due to target environment verification errors.
INFO: Adding ExitStatus PREREQ_FAILURE to the exit status set
```

Comment: Are you sure that 11.2 was certified on Windows 8.1?  I'm not looking at the certification matrix at the moment but I wouldn't be surprised if you needed to have at least Oracle 12.1 to go with Windows 8.1.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. More here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e49703/toc.htm#BGBEBFIF

Comment: Are you running 64 or 32 bit Win 8.1?

Comment: It is a 64 bit system

Comment: I think that may be the root of your issue.