# Oracle Universal Installer Terminates execution

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, windows-server-2016

I am installing **oracle 12c on Windows server 2016 OS**. But just after double-clicking on `setup.exe` my installer disappears without any progress. I am running setup.exe file with **administrator** privilege. Also **disabled UAC**.

When I checked log files content of the same was

```
Using paramFile: C:\abc\database\install\oraparam.ini
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 4294967296    Passed
The number of files bootstrapped for the jre is 0.
The number of files bootstrapped for the oui is 0.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112271/oracle-universal-installer-disappearing-before-completing

Comment: No luck..! Windows and setup both are compatible 64bit version..

Comment: What about this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483757/139985

Comment: Hard luck this time also :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the solution ... but when I searched for the message:

```
 The number of files bootstrapped for the jre is ...
```

most of the hits had a non-zero number.  The three hits that I found which had zero as the number all mentioned that they were installing into a filesystem with 2TB or more free space.  And one of them even said that they managed to get the installer so work by creating a large temporary file so that the free space was less than 2TB.

I suggest that you try that.

Comment: Seems relevant. Because just now i have shifted from MBR file system to GBT and made each partition more than 2 TB in size.. so what should i try, making partition less than 2TB in size keeping file system GBT or should I change file system to MBR also..

Comment: I suggest just create a great big temporary file ....

Comment: Worked like charm.  !! Thank you very much. Trying for this issue since 3 days. I wonder what would cause issue if free size was more than 2TB.

Comment: My guess is that it is trying getting the amount of free space (in 1024 byte blocks), in order to see if there is enough space to install.  But 2TB / 1024 is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and it is botching the calculation.

Comment: for those who got confused by "large temporary file" like me, it means create any file to consume the space that you delete it later.

You may find this link useful, [Dummy File Generators](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/dummy-file-generator-software)