# Need help installing ODAC 122011x64 so I can connect ADW to Power BI

Tags: oracle, installation, powerbi

So I have successfully installed Oracle DB 19c and connected it to Oracle SQL Developer. I am able to create tables and run queries. Furthermore, I can connect to ADW with both python and SQL Developer and any changes that I commit are seen in all locations. I am trying to connect the ADW database to Power BI. I am running all this on a personal Windows 10 Pro laptop with plenty of SSD & RAM.

In a new window of Power BI I click Get Data and then Oracle Database followed by Connect. When I do this I get a pop up that says:

```
The recommended provider ('Oracle.DataAccess.Client') is not installed. You can continue with your current provider, however it has been deprecated and may not work correctly.
```

I clock OK. Enter my Server as the TNS Name that I have used for my python and SQL Developer instances. In my ADW database, I have a table called TEST. It's a simple table with 1 column with the years 2015 through 2020 in it. Been using this to test to see if things are working. So I click on the DirectQuery and run the SQL statement SELECT * FROM TEST under the Advanced options menu and select OK. A sign in window pops up and I select the Database table and enter my correct ADW username and password. The same one that I can use to access this table from SQL Developer and then select Connect. When I do, I get this error:

```
Details: "The provider being used is deprecated: 'System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.'. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=272376 to install the official provider."
```

So I go to the website and download the ODAC122011_x64 file from Oracle and unzip it. When I double click the setup.exe file inside the directory I get a yes/no user control account menu and I select yes and then a command prompt window flashes very quickly and then nothing happens. I ran a super slow motion capture from my phone to capture what the command window showed and below is what I see:

```
Starting Oracle Universal Starter...
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 color Higher than 256 . Actual 4294967290   Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2020 09:20_09-04 {???}
Please wait .._
```

It does nothing after this I have tried running the oui.exe file under the install subdirectory and get nothing and I have tried running the install.exe file in Oracle Universal Installer that I acquired when installing Oracle DB 19c and I get the following error when I target the install.exe file for installation:

```
OUI-10118:C/Users/{my username}/Downloads/ODAC122011_x64/Setup.exe is either a directory or a corrupt file. Specify a valid filename.
```

This is a file that I just directly downloaded from Oracle's website and unzipped to a directory with no spaces in the directory location. I have the latest version of Java installed (JDK 15).

I am not sure the proper work around here. Why can't I get my Power BI to connect to my Oracle ADW table using the methods described in [this article](https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/microsoft-powerbi-connection-adw.pdf). Those are the instructions that I used. It appears that I need this ODAC application but I don't understand why it won't install.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Thanks!

Edit: I am using 64-bit on each application.

Update: Still having issues. I checked the log and this is what I am seeing:

Using paramFile:

```
C:\Oracle\Oracle_PowerBI_ODAC\ODAC122011_x64\install\oraparam.ini


Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 4294967296    Passed


The number of files bootstrapped for the jre is 0.

The number of files bootstrapped for the oui is 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

the client version need not match the server version, Removing all other versions, and making sure that I had the x64 version,

You need the latest ODP.net library to use Oracle. Please download it here:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Comment: I am unable to install ODP.net for the exact same reasons mentioned in my original post. The command prompt pops open and shut in a blink of the eye and then nothing happens. I tried Reinstalling Java 15 and restarting my computer and nothing is working. Need help.

Comment: Check this document https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17559_01/em.111/e12255/b_oui_appendix.htm

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution after reviewing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495100/oracle-universal-installer-terminates-execution). Apparently having over 2TB of free space on a hard drive causes this problem. You have to go into command prompt and create a temporary file to get your free space under 2TBs using something like this:

```
fsutil file createnew temp_1TB_file 1200000000000
```

Run the setup.exe again and then delete the temp file after.

Update: After doing all this I still was running into the same issues in Power BI. Then I read the troubleshooting notes from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-oracle-database#install-the-oracle-client) more closely and realized that I might have found the problem when it said:

```
If you downloaded Power BI Desktop from the Microsoft Store, you might be unable to connect to Oracle databases because of an Oracle driver issue.
```

I uninstalled the PowerBI Desktop that I had installed from Microsoft Store and installed it from the download from its website and tried connecting to Oracle ADW again through PowerBI and IT WORKED!!! So much troubleshooting but it finally works!